# Is there a difference between Main() in a structure versus a class?

Tags: c#, class, struct, entry-point

Let's say in C# I had my `Main()` function in an `Entry` class that exists solely to house the entry-point. I would do it like such:

```
public class Entry
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        ...

    }

}
```

I consider this pretty typical, and at least in some Java projects at work I have seen classes exist just for the `main()` function and never thought twice about it. But while I have been learning more about C# and structures, I tried to do the following:

```
public struct Entry
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        ...

    }

}
```

and it worked exactly the same visually. So, assuming that your entry point in C# contains only your `Main()` function, does making it's container a `struct` have any actual difference compared to a `class` at runtime?

Comment: The entry point for an executable project **is** the `Main` method. And an .exe project can only have one of them. You can have any number of classes or structs in a project, but one and only one of them can implement `static void Main()`. Understanding that, I guess the remaining question here would be *"what is the difference between a class and a struct"*, which is well documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is, in regards to an entry-point (and your constraints) there is no appreciable difference apart from a few bytes here and there. However, let's visit the documentation:

[Main() and command-line arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# application. (Libraries and
> services do not require a Main method as an entry point.) When the
> application is started, the Main method is the first method that is
> invoked.
>
> **Overview**
>
> - The Main method is the entry point of an executable program; it is where the program control starts and ends.
> - Main is declared inside a **class or struct**. Main must be static and it need not be public. (In the earlier example, it receives the
>   default access of private.) The enclosing class or struct is not
>   required to be static.
>
> ...